# Hostinger host and tk domain optimal DNS configuration

Tags: web-hosting, dns, dns-servers

I want to configure tk domain with hostinger. I don't want to use the redirect option, so I'm trying to set the tk dns. In the image below are shown the parameters of hostinger that I have put in dns service conf on tk

[image]

Actually the website on tk link doesn't work, but I don't know if this is due the dns propagation time, or is caused by a wrong configuration,
Could someone confirm that the used parameters are right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The posted configuration was correct, the issue was caused by DNS cache of the OS, after flushing cache with

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

everything works.

Answer (score 1):

From the image that you provided, I do not see an IP address for your domain name  mysitename.tk. As well, an A record and CNAME record for www.mysitename.tk is redundant. I recommend CNAME over using an A record and to only use an A record if CNAME does not work. The only other thing you need to do is to set the hostinger name servers within your registrar control panel so that and DNS query can find your host DNS settings.

This answer is based on the information that was provided. If there are more issues, please update the question with more details including registrar control panel images. Images really do help a lot!

Update: Here is some background that you will need based upon what I can see.

- Your domain name registrar likely has two name servers already
  defined. It is likely two of their own name servers. These will need
  to be changed to the name servers of your web host that your web host
  will provide.
- You will need an A record for mysitename.tk with an IP address that
  your web host will provide.
- You will need an CNAME record for www.mysitename.tk that points to
  mysitename.tk.
- You will need an MX record which you already have defined as
  mx.hostinger.in which appears to be correct.

Comment: There isn't shown IP number but in the picture Is shown that I have taken the IP from the field Website IP address found on my hostinger website details. If I leave all 2 *A record* fields plus *cname* fields is simply redundant or can cause problems?

Comment: In regard to the A record and CNAME, I cannot tell you that there will be problems, but I have been at this since ARPA-Net (which became the Internet) and was a webhost for many years; I would delete the A record for www and leave the CNAME. If that dow not work, then I would use an A record and delete the CNAME. I do not know your control panel, but I would expect to see IP addresses for your A records in the fields to the right. You would know best on this of course.

Comment: Ok Thanks. I have removed the 2 -A records- leaving only the -CNAME-, now I'm waitin to see what's happens.

Comment: You will need one A record for mysitename.tk. The IP address you will need from your web hosting company. Updating answer.

Comment: I have tried again and my initial posted configuration was correct. The issue was caused by DNS cache of the OS, after dns flushing everything works. Thanks anyway

Comment: I just up-voted your answer. Congrats!! It had been so long since I had to flush ipconfig that I totally forgot about it.